# CakePHP "Object not Found" in simple tutorial

Tags: cakephp

Building first web application with CakePHP, the root application works fine in browser: "BlogTutorial" shows the default CakePHP page and layout. I conclude from this that Apache is doing its thing.
However with even the simplest MVC model, e.g. The Blog Tutorial, when I try to use "BlogTutorial/Posts/index", I get "Object not found".
The Model is called "Post", controller "PostsController", and the view "Posts" with "index.ctp". I thought I had everything covered, but apparently not.
( Repeated this with a different tutorial, with similar failed results.)
Any pointers?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you share a link to tutorial you followed and some code you wrote?

Comment: instead of "BlogTutorial/Posts/index" use ths 'BlogTutorial/posts/index"

Comment: Tutorial was the 15 minute tutorial on CakePHP website http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html, replicated code as directed in tutorial. It seems that no views are being generated, apart from the root view for the local site.

Comment: If anyone is interested...it turned out to be an issue with the virtual hosts configuration in Apache running locally. The default code needed to be extended to allow override and use of syslinks. There is a helpful section on this topic in the tutorial mentioned above.